# Getting a user inputted equation

Tags: python, math, input, calculator

I'm currently trying to let a user input their own equation for my calculator. If I run it with just my own equation, it works perfectly, however I can't get it to work from a user input. Any advice? Thanks
This part of the code works

```
 def function(x):
     equation = 3*exp(x)
     return equation
```

When I change to a user input, It doesn't

```
 def function(x):
     equation = input('Insert your equation)
    return equation
```

Comment: You might want to look into the `eval` function.

Comment: I don't get why this question got downvoted. Many programmers who're learning Python often want to do this kind of a task.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `eval()` function. For example:

```
from math import exp


def function(x):
     equation = eval(user_input)
     return equation


user_input = "3*exp(x)"
x = 2
print(function(x))
```

But, citing [realpython](https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/), "eval() is considered insecure because it allows you (or your users) to dynamically execute arbitrary Python code. This is considered bad programming practice because the code that you're reading (or writing) is not the code that you'll execute."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Comment: There we go! It's important to include the caveats when suggesting a bad practice in an answer

Comment: I added that, in general, eval is considered a bad practice. But in this particular case, it suits the OP's needs. I was going to do it in the edit. :)

Comment: I noticed you added it. That's why I changed my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: Thank you! Massive help @kenticent